# BigQuery table decorators ranges

Tags: google-bigquery

We are using table decorators to query incremental data in BQ.
I would like to avoid querying same data in 2 different increments (ranges).
The question is how do BQ treat the edges of the decorators range?
is it

```
"end decorator >= range >= start decorator"?
"end decorator > range > start decorator"? 
"end decorator >= range > start decorator"?
other?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the start time and end time are inclusive (I just looked at the code to verify).

```
end decorator >= commit time >= start decorator
```

So if you have 3 times, 10000, 20000 and 30000, (of course your timestamps will look more like 1387470149000, but the numbers are easier to read if they're small) you'd use:

```
table@0-9999
table@10000-19999
table@20000-29999
table@30000-
```

@0 is special, meaning 'the oldest available time', which is 7 days ago or when the table was created'.
That would divide the table into the partitions of "oldest time -> 9.999 seconds, 10 seconds -> 19.999 seconds, 20 seconds -> 29.999 seconds, and 30 seconds through now".

Thinking a bit about this, it seems like the end time should be non-inclusive (`end > commit time >= start`). Any votes for changing it?

Comment: I would have the start not inclusive: end >= commit time > start. I find it more comfortable... each is fine as long as its clear (and well documented :)) (adding or subtracting 1 from the edge is easy...)

Answer (score 1):

I found "table@0-9999" could be problematic, since Bigquery will give you:

```
Error: Not Found: Table project:dataset.table@0-9999
```

[update]
Actually, Bigquery won't allow a start time before table creation time in table decorator