# Big Query @0 table decorator

Tags: google-bigquery

Following Jordans response to my previous "BQ table decorators" question ([BigQuery table decorators ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678552/bigquery-table-decorators-ranges)), we tried to use @0 table decorator.

It seems as something doesn't work as expected... (I re-wrote my query on wikipedia sample data)

```
SELECT title FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia@1387809421420000-1387809421420159]
```

runs OK (no results, but its expected)

```
SELECT title FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia@0]
```

returns entire table (not just past 7 days)

```
SELECT title FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia@0-1387809421420159]
```

Fails ... 
Any idea? Is it a bug or something we did wrong? 
Many thanks

Comment: thanks, investigating...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT title FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia@0]` should return the entire table. @0 means something like "show me how the table looked 7 days ago" (with 7 days being the oldest available snapshot.

Followoing the same logic, `SELECT title FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia@0-1387809421420159]` should show you the changes since that date until MSEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(1387809421420159), but that behavior (when starting at 0) is not currently supported.